# Why is this Bootstrap row covering more width than the screen width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to insert feedback form in my website. I have an email field and text message field, with a send button. All of this is inside a Bootstrap row. But this row is taking more width than the screen width. I want the row to fit to 100% of the screen width. Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row" id="getintouchrow" style="background-color: #1C2833;border: none;">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <center>
        <h1 style="margin-top: 100px;font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;color: #B2BABB">Sample Text</h1>
        <h5 style="font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;color: #B2BABB">Sample Text<br></h5>
      </center>
      <form style="background-color: transparent">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);border-top:none;border-radius: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;">> </div>
        <div class="form-group">

          <textarea class="form-control" id="Textarea" rows="3" placeholder="Type here" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);border-top:none;border-radius: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;"></textarea><br><br>
        </div>
        <center>
          <center><a href="#" class=" contact-mission btn btn-outline-dark" style="font-size: 22px;width: 300px;outline-width: 50px;height: 50px;font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;margin-bottom: 70px;">Send Message</a></center>
        </center>
      </form>

      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="py-5 text-white" style="border-top-color: #1C2833">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook fa-3x text-white"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
              <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter fa-3x text-white"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-instagram text-white fa-3x"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
              <p>© Copyright 2018 - All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bootstrap row has margin-right and margin left -15px value

Comment: Bootstrap requires a `container` or `container-fluid` to be present in order to use the grid system. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: your rows and text boxes are aligned perfectly what do you want make your questions more clear

Answer (score 5):

Since you are working with Bootstrap. The structure of bootstrap says all the content should be wrap in class `container`. Which is followed by `row` which have columns inside. Since row styling are:

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Where it is giving margin left and right -15px, to cover padding which will come from parent `container` class. So please wrap your `row` with `container` to get desired result
Useful Link for more understanding of grid:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1):

Hi if row is expanding more than the width please make sure`row{border:0px;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;max-width:100%; }`

Answer (score 1):

see because in .row there is **negative margin** set for left and right both by 15px. that's why its taking width more than screen size, so you can user in proper structure allowed by **bootstrap** convention.

**container > row > col**

it will take whole screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Container-fluid" class instead of row.

Please Refer Below Fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/s5xbgykv/)

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="getintouchrow" style="background-color: #1C2833;border: none;">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <center>
        <h1 style="margin-top: 100px;font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;color: #B2BABB">Sample Text</h1>
        <h5 style="font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;color: #B2BABB">Sample Text<br></h5>
      </center>
      <form style="background-color: transparent">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);border-top:none;border-radius: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;">> </div>
        <div class="form-group">

          <textarea class="form-control" id="Textarea" rows="3" placeholder="Type here" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);border-top:none;border-radius: none;border-left: none;border-right: none;"></textarea><br><br>
        </div>
        <center>
          <center><a href="#" class=" contact-mission btn btn-outline-dark" style="font-size: 22px;width: 300px;outline-width: 50px;height: 50px;font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;margin-bottom: 70px;">Send Message</a></center>
        </center>
      </form>

      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="py-5 text-white" style="border-top-color: #1C2833">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook fa-3x text-white"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
              <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter fa-3x text-white"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-instagram text-white fa-3x"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
              <p>© Copyright 2018 - All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```